# How to Retrieve Value from select array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the below code for select array in html

```
<select name="selection[1]">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
<select name="selection[2]">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

How do i retrieve the values from this select in javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: Which select? Which values? And more importantly, what codes have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give id for each dropdown and get value like this:

```
<select name="selection[1]" id="selection1">
<option selected="selected">1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
<select name="selection[2]" id="selection2">
<option selected="selected">1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
<script>
var e = document.getElementById("selection1");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
console.log(strUser);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```js
$('[name^="selection"]').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('name'));
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="selection[1]">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
<select name="selection[2]">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

First, you have to add id="selection[1]" and id="selection[2]" in the select control respectively, then you can call this function to get the selected value and text.

```
<script>
function Getdropdown1()
{
var e = document.getElementById("selection[1]");
var selectedValue1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var selectedText1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
}
</script>

<script>
function Getdropdown2()
{
var e = document.getElementById("selection[2]");
var selectedValue2 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var selectedText2 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try :

```
document.getElementsByName('selection[1]')[0].value
document.getElementsByName('selection[2]')[0].value
```